# Angular 5 create matmenutriggerfor in *ngFor loop

Tags: angular5

I am trying to create a menu dynamic for my ecommerce and i got this error:

```
Error: mat-menu-trigger: must pass in an mat-menu instance!
```

Did anyone know how to solve this error.
How can i do `[matMenuTriggerFor]` and `#main_menu` dynamic?

I have multiple shops in my list! Its simple as that.
Only need these two attr in dynamic format.

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="i" *ngFor="let shop of shopey; let 
i=index">{{shop.name}}
</button>
<mat-menu #main_menu="matMenu">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let shop of shopey">
 </ng-container>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: Fix formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following...

Move your `*ngFor` loop to a span wrapper

```
 <span *ngFor="let shop of shopey; let i=index">
```

And then change `#main_menu` to `#i`

```
<span *ngFor="let shop of shopey; let i=index">
 <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="i" >{{shop.name}}
 </button>
 <mat-menu #i="matMenu">
  <ng-container>
    this is a test of the container
  </ng-container>
 </mat-menu>
</span>
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wu6dl4?embed=1&file=app/menu-overview-example.ts